# Не могу понять почему видает ошибку в функции?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int **matrix_new(int m, int n)
{
    int **matrix = new int *[m];    
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[n];

    }
    return matrix;
}

void  matrix_random(int **matrix, int m, int n)
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]=rand()%10;
        }
    }
}

void matrix_print(int **matrix, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cout << "| ";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";

        }
        cout <<"|"<< endl;
    }
}

int **matrix_sum(int **matrix, int m, int n)
{
    int **sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + matrix[m][n];
    }
    return sum;
}

int **matrix_sort(int **matrix, int m, int index1,int index2)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        temp = matrix[i][index2];
        matrix[i][index2] = matrix[i][index1];
        matrix[i][index1] = temp;
    }
    return matrix;
}

int matrix_form(int **matrix, int m, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int b = **matrix_sum(matrix, m, i);
        int index1 = i;

        for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            int c = **matrix_sum(matrix, m, j);
            int index2 = j;
            if(c<b)
            {
                b = c;
                matrix_sort(matrix, m, index1, index2 );
            }
        }

    }

    return **matrix ;
 }

int main()
{
    const int a = 4;
    const int b = 5;
    const int c = 8;

    int  **A = matrix_new (a, b);
    int  **B = matrix_new (b, c);

    matrix_random(A, a, b);
    matrix_random(B, b, c);

    cout << "Matrutsa A=" << endl;
    matrix_print(A, a, b);
    cout << "Matrutsa B=" << endl;
    matrix_print(B, b, c);

    matrix_form(A, a, b);
    matrix_form(B, b, c);

    cout << "Matrutsa A=" << endl;
    matrix_print(A, a, b);
    cout << "Matrutsa B=" << endl;
    matrix_print(B, b, c);

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

в функии martrix_sum  что то идет не так как надо....
помогите хорошим словом)
 И если кто то может помогите исправить потому что я не слишком понимаю ошибку, я хочу чтоб даная програма в функции matrix_form  отсортировало масиви  по столбцах,  по суме их елементов от min до  max
Большое спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, если Вы получаете какую-то ошибку, приводите ее текст в сообщении, не заставляйте нас работать экстрасенсами.

Comment: Пример сначала следует привести к виду [mcve]. Потом можно будет и поговорить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int matrix_sum(int **matrix, int m, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        sum += matrix[m][n];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Зачем Вы вообще возвращаете **двойной** указатель из функции, которая должна возвращать `int`? Уберите указатели из этой функции. И скорректируйте свой код в местах использования этой функции. Вообще, при написании этого кода: `int** sum = 0;` Вы могли бы вспомнить свой же код из функции `matrix_new` и обратить внимание на некорректность инициализации. В следующий раз будьте внимательней. Еще могу порекомендовать использовать `nullptr` вместо `0` или `NULL`, это правильнее (см. ситуации преобразования).

Comment: Идеалом совершенства было бы сделать typedef Matrix int**; чтобы не путаться.

Comment: @test123 лучше using Matrix = int**; в современном мире же живем... А еще лучше не заморачиваться и использовать Matrix из библиотеки;)